# SSIS Excel Import - First row getting skipped

Tags: ssis, ssdt, ssis-2012, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017(SSDT) with SSIS(2012). I'm trying to import an Excel file, but the issue is that the first row is getting skipped.

I've unchecked *First row has column names* in Excel Connection Manager, but in vain.

Please advice on how to import the first row.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy using the Wizard:

1. In your Project, drag a data flow task onto the board

[image]

2. Double-click the data flow task. being inside the data stream, drag an excel source.

[image]

3. then we create a new connection to excel by clicking on excel source.

[image]

4. we look for the excel file that we want to import and select: "the first row has column names"

[image]

5. we select the table or the view that we have in the excel sheet.

[image]

6. With this we would already have the process to import the excel data to any destination ...

[image]

good Luck...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I knew the process. Found out that its not importing if the first col. name starts with the letter 'S' like in the word 'SL #'. Tried with other chars and its fine. What will be the issue?

Comment: SSIS 2012 versions have a lot of trouble updating the views, in many cases like this it happened to me that the workflow went crazy and I had to delete the task and recreate the process. The other way is to create an odbc for your excel sheet or create code in c # / vb.net with a script task with which you can import the data from your sheet...

Comment: You can also convert your excel sheet to .txt, delimited by "tab", "," or ";" With this you save the odbc work and it would be more practical! Good luck...